# Empty exception when trying to enable development mode

Tags: zend-framework2

I use [zf-development-mode](https://github.com/zfcampus/zf-development-mode) to manage dev configs. When I fire `php public/index.php development enable` it produces the following output:

```
======================================================================
   The application has thrown an exception!
======================================================================


----------------------------------------------------------------------
:

======================================================================
   Previous Exception(s):
```

Now I’m unable to debug this. Any ideas, how I can make the exception visible on the CLI? There aren’t any problems/exceptions, when I run the ZF2 app in the browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This also happens when `display_exceptions` key in `view_manager` config section is set to `false`. Try editing your local config something like this:

```
'view_manager' => array(
    'display_exceptions' => true,
)
```

I had the same problem and it worked for me.